# Calling a function that exists inside another function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

i just want to know how i would include a function inside another function. TRying to query my database for users 3 levels deep.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Referrals;

use Auth;

/**
* 
*/
class EloquentReferrals implements ReferralRepository
{

function __construct(User $model)
{
    return $this->model->all();
}


function __construct(User $model)
{
    return $this->model->all();
}

public function getallreferrals()
{
    return $this->model->where('referred_by', Auth::user()->referral_id)->get();
}

public function getallreferrals2gen()
{

}

public function getallreferrals3gen(){

}

public function getallreferralsbyID($id){

}

public function getallreferrals2gen($id){

}

public function getallreferrals3gen($id){

}


}
```

in my repository the get all referrals function returns all direct referrals. I want to use the result to get the referrals of those referrals. How do i include it inside my getallreferrals2gen function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you show an example?

Comment: `return $this->getallreferrals();` modified with whatever additional logic you need; e.g. `return $this->getallreferrals()->where('level', 2);`

Comment: Farkie that is the example. Am trying to get referrals of a referral of a referral. Querying the database for a user's referral using a uniquely generated referral_id

Comment: Mark Baker thanks a lot. Though i want to use the value returned in $this->getallreferrals() as a logic. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$this` to call a function from a function in the same class;

property, like so;

```
public function getallreferrals()
{
    return $this->model->where('referred_by', Auth::user()->referral_id)->get();
}

public function getallreferrals2gen()
{
     $this->getallreferrals()(
}
```

Comment: so i can do these?    public function getallreferrals()
    {
        return $this->model->where('referred_by', Auth::user()->referral_id)-
     >get();
     }

     public function getallreferrals2gen()
     {
          return $this->model->where('referred_by', $this->getallreferrals())->get();
     }

Comment: that's the way to do it.

Comment: but the function call its the way should be!

Comment: Okay. So there is no way around it? The result will be an array of object. I need to get a property inside of it.

Comment: try to use first() instead of get() and check what u get dd value, or pluck('name of column')